# HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error in Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat

I recently created an API using Spring Boot which I deployed to Tomcat. For now, I have a single endpoint that I am trying to hit using Postman. I have modified the server's web.xml and tomcat-users.xml files according to [this article](http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html).

### web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>readonly</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyApp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyApp</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Role for restricted resources</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

### tomcat-users.xml

```
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin" />
```

---

I am then using the same credentials using basic authentication in Postman (user: admin, password: admin). But I still get this HTTP 403 error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is the name of the app the name of the JAR or is it the name of the app inside the POM?